# ASP.NET Core Controllers, Views and ViewModels in Separate DLLs

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP Core MVC website setup using [Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763233.aspx), so basically each controller and associated views and view models are in a single folder.  I want to extend this to have each Feature in a separate DLL.  So for example, I would have an "Accounts" dll that had AccountController and associated Views and I would even have a "Shared" dll that had any shared view stuff like _Layout.cshtml

To illustrate what I am trying to do, the image below was taken from [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763233.aspx).  I want each red box to be a separate dll.

[image: red boxes in separate dlls]

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Something you need to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: So what is your problem? There is a documentation post about such kind of discovering: [Application Parts in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts)

Comment: Feature Folders are a great idea.  But a project per feature, will add a ton work of work.  If you need one Feature to be a micro-service.  I recommend extracting that when you needed it.  I actually strive to deploy everything as a single dll if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Create a new ASP.NET Core app that contains only one folder named **Areas**.
2. Inside the Areas folder, add a new folder (name of the feature). For instance, **Ninjas**.
3. Add a reference to this project into the main Web project.
4. Configure the Web app to handle Areas in the Routes, something like this:

   ```
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "areaRoute", 
           template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "default",
           template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   });
   ```